# Retrieving HTML from MongoDB for use in angular project

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, summernote

I am using summernote editor in my project, while storing the content its storing as string,

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('indexController', function($scope){

$scope.data = [{
text:"<p><strong style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;is simply dummy<i> <b>text of the printing</b></i> and <u>typesetting industry.</u> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p><ol><li><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">I</span>t has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li><li>It has survived not only five<sup>fgfggfgfg.</sup></li><li>kjkjkjk<sub>jkjk</sub></li><li>ghgfhgfhgfhfghgfhfghgfhfghgfdhgjgj.</li></ol>"
},{
text:"<p><strong style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;is simply dummy<i> <b>text of the printing</b></i> and <u>typesetting industry.</u> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p><ol><li><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">I</span>t has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li><li>It has survived not only five<sup>fgfggfgfg.</sup></li><li>kjkjkjk<sub>jkjk</sub></li><li>ghgfhgfhgfhfghgfhfghgfhfghgfdhgjgj.</li></ol>"
} ]

});
```

```css
.divClass{
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="indexController">

<div ng-repeat="txt in data" class="divClass">{{txt.text}}</div>
</div>
```

i tried **ng-bind-html** also but its not working, please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `$sce.trustAsHtml` to render the string in to html. make sure to inject the `$sce` to the controller.

create a filter and use it in the html

```
app.filter('render',function($sce){
      return function(html) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
      }
})
```

call it in the template using `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-repeat="txt in data" class="divClass">
      <div ng-bind-html="txt.text | render">

      </div>
</div>
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('render',function($sce){
  return function(html) {
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
app.controller('indexController', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.data = [{
text:"<p><strong style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;is simply dummy<i> <b>text of the printing</b></i> and <u>typesetting industry.</u> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p><ol><li><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">I</span>t has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li><li>It has survived not only five<sup>fgfggfgfg.</sup></li><li>kjkjkjk<sub>jkjk</sub></li><li>ghgfhgfhgfhfghgfhfghgfhfghgfdhgjgj.</li></ol>"
},{
text:"<p><strong style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">&nbsp;is simply dummy<i> <b>text of the printing</b></i> and <u>typesetting industry.</u> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span></p><ol><li><span style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;\">I</span>t has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li><li>It has survived not only five<sup>fgfggfgfg.</sup></li><li>kjkjkjk<sub>jkjk</sub></li><li>ghgfhgfhgfhfghgfhfghgfhfghgfdhgjgj.</li></ol>"
} ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="indexController">
 
<div ng-repeat="txt in data" class="divClass">
  <div ng-bind-html="txt.text | render">
  
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working for single value, but i need to apply this for repeated value, i edited the qus, how to do it for repeat